# How to dragdrop on a disabled TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I want to make a `DragDrop` on a TextBox which has `Enabled=false` property, but `DragDrop` is disabled as the control is disabled. Is there a way to make it or it has to be `Enabled=true`

```
private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
   if (files.Length < 1)
       return;
   if (new string[] { ".txt", ".csv" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(files[0])))
   textBox1.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[0]);
   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from typing or copy/pasting the path into the textbox (why?) then you are just using the wrong control.  it should then be a Label instead of a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ReadOnly property instead of the Enabled property.  A ReadOnly control accepts Drop events but does not allow the user to otherwise modify its content.

ReadOnly likely gives the effect and behavior you seek without having to implement complicated state tracking code and doing so will keep your user interface congruent with standard practices.